# Requirements for ZURB Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation, bower, zurb-foundation-6

What are the requirements for ZURB Foundation 6?
The docs are not clear: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html

They say:

> To get started, first install the framework files using Bower or npm.
>
> ```
> cd projectname
>   npm install
>   bower install
> ```

So is Bower a requirement for using Foundation ZURB template with Sass or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower is needed. The assets of the foundation framework itself are loaded via bower into bower_components (and other things like jquery, what-input and so on).

The node modules (installed via npm install) are needded to run the `foundation watch` and `foundation build` commands, which use the assets in the bower_components folder to build an serve the compiled pages from the dist directory.